# bootstrap datepicker disable past date in datepicker

Tags: jquery, laravel, datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I want to disable past date in datepicker in my laravel framework but it is not working

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datepicker(function(){
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        todayHighlight:'TRUE',
        minDate: today,
        autoclose: true
 });
```

Disabling past date bootstrap/jquery datepicker

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datepicker(function(){
        startDate: new Date(),
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        todayHighlight:'TRUE',
        autoclose: true
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datepicker(function(){
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        todayHighlight:'TRUE',
        minDate: 0,
        autoclose: true
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
minDate: today
```

With

```
minDate: 0
```

Hope that would help you in what you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datepicker(function(){
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        startDate: "od",
        todayHighlight: true,
        todayBtn : true
 });
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : i am getting this error for that code

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code i used this for datetime picker(working for me)

```
$(function () 
    {
      var curr_date = new Date();
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(
      {
          defaultDate: curr_date,
          minDate: curr_date,
          format : 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
          icons: {
              time: "fa fa-clock-o",
              date: "fa fa-calendar",
              up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
              down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
          }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this code:

```
var dateToday = new Date();       
            $(".datepicker").val($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", new Date()));        
            $('.datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-prev').remove();
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                minDate: dateToday,
                onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                        instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                    dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
                    if (date < dateToday) {                 
                        $(this).datepicker("setDate", dateToday);
                    }
                }
            });
```